# Android with Volley, Gson : how to define class for following json response

Tags: android, json, gson, android-volley

My Expected Json Response

```
{
  "first_name": "Rajesh",
  "contacts": [
    {
      "id": "c200",
      "name": "rajesh",
      "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
      "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
      "gender": "male",
      "phone": {
        "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
        "home": "00 000000",
        "office": "00 000000"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "c201",
      "name": "ravi",
      "email": "ravi_depp@gmail.com",
      "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
      "gender": "male",
      "phone": {
        "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
        "home": "00 000000",
        "office": "00 000000"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

GsonRequest Class to make request and get response

```
public class GsonRequest<T> extends Request<T> {

    private final Gson gson = new Gson();
    private final Class<T> clazz;
    private final Map<String, String> headers;
    private final Listener<T> listener;


    public GsonRequest(String url, Class<T> clazz, Map<String, String> headers,
        Listener<T> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.GET, url, errorListener);

        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.headers = headers;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        return headers != null ? headers : super.getHeaders();
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
        listener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String json = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(gson.fromJson(json, clazz),
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }
}
```

My question is how to write class which can i pass GsonRequest class and get response
I tried http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to generate class for my json response

Right now i am making request as follow

```
  GsonRequest<MyClass> gsonRequest = new GsonRequest<MyClass>(url,MyClass.class, null,createMyReqSuccessListener(), createMyReqErrorListener());
```

My Response Listener function

```
private Response.Listener<MyClass> createMyReqSuccessListener() {
        return new Response.Listener<MyClass>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(MyClass response) {

                txtView.setText("success" + response.first_name);
            }
        };
    }
```

Class for json response

```
public class MyClass {
    public String first_name;
    public List<Contact> contacts;

    public class Contact {
        public String id;
        public String name;
        public String email;
        public String address;
        public String gender;
        public Phone phone;
    }

    public class Phone {
        public String mobile;
        public String home;
        public String office;
    }
}
```

Comment: pleaes, show us how do you make request and error log

Comment: please check edited question

Comment: in "createMyReqSuccessListener()" getting null response. pls check edited question for function

Comment: @Yazazzello thank you for your quick response, ed's class solve my problem

Comment: actually I've checked: both json classes worked well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Response {
    public String first_name;
    public List<Contact> contacts;

    public class Contact {
        public String id;
        public String name;
        public String email;
        public String address;
        public String gender;
        public Phone phone;
    }

    public class Phone {
        public String mobile;
        public String home;
        public String office;
    }
}
```

like this

Comment: @Ed George thank you so much, your class is working like charm. Just one question is there any service like "http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/" for generating this class from json

Comment: @RD1819: this is rainash's answer, Ed George helps him to edit his answer :)

Answer (score 0):

There is useful web service for generating classes http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
just select Source type: JSON and Annotation style: GSON

here is what have been done for your example:

```
    -----------------------------------com.example.Contact.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Contact {

@Expose
private String id;
@Expose
private String name;
@Expose
private String email;
@Expose
private String address;
@Expose
private String gender;
@Expose
private Phone phone;

/**
* 
* @return
* The id
*/
public String getId() {
return id;
}

/**
* 
* @param id
* The id
*/
public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The name
*/
public String getName() {
return name;
}

/**
* 
* @param name
* The name
*/
public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The email
*/
public String getEmail() {
return email;
}

/**
* 
* @param email
* The email
*/
public void setEmail(String email) {
this.email = email;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The address
*/
public String getAddress() {
return address;
}

/**
* 
* @param address
* The address
*/
public void setAddress(String address) {
this.address = address;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The gender
*/
public String getGender() {
return gender;
}

/**
* 
* @param gender
* The gender
*/
public void setGender(String gender) {
this.gender = gender;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The phone
*/
public Phone getPhone() {
return phone;
}

/**
* 
* @param phone
* The phone
*/
public void setPhone(Phone phone) {
this.phone = phone;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Example {

@SerializedName("first_name")
@Expose
private String firstName;
@Expose
private List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();

/**
* 
* @return
* The firstName
*/
public String getFirstName() {
return firstName;
}

/**
* 
* @param firstName
* The first_name
*/
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
this.firstName = firstName;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The contacts
*/
public List<Contact> getContacts() {
return contacts;
}

/**
* 
* @param contacts
* The contacts
*/
public void setContacts(List<Contact> contacts) {
this.contacts = contacts;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Phone.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Phone {

@Expose
private String mobile;
@Expose
private String home;
@Expose
private String office;

/**
* 
* @return
* The mobile
*/
public String getMobile() {
return mobile;
}

/**
* 
* @param mobile
* The mobile
*/
public void setMobile(String mobile) {
this.mobile = mobile;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The home
*/
public String getHome() {
return home;
}

/**
* 
* @param home
* The home
*/
public void setHome(String home) {
this.home = home;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The office
*/
public String getOffice() {
return office;
}

/**
* 
* @param office
* The office
*/
public void setOffice(String office) {
this.office = office;
}

}
```

Comment: The question states that OP is using `gson` and not `Jackson`

Comment: changed to gson annotations

Comment: hi Yazazz.. i already tried  http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org but not able to parse json data

Comment: @RD1819 please, give more information what have you done

Answer (score 0):

For Json object:

```
public static GsonRequest<DummyObject> getDummyObject
(
        Response.Listener<DummyObject> listener,
        Response.ErrorListener errorListener
)
{
    final String url = "http://www.mocky.io/v2/55973508b0e9e4a71a02f05f";

    final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(DummyObject.class, new DummyObjectDeserializer())
            .create();

    return new GsonRequest<>
            (
                    url,
                    new TypeToken<DummyObject>() {}.getType(),
                    gson,
                    listener,
                    errorListener
            );
}
```

For JSON Array:

```
public static GsonRequest<ArrayList<DummyObject>> getDummyObjectArray
(
        Response.Listener<ArrayList<DummyObject>> listener,
        Response.ErrorListener errorListener
)
{
    final String url = "http://www.mocky.io/v2/5597d86a6344715505576725";

    final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(DummyObject.class, new DummyObjectDeserializer())
            .create();

    return new GsonRequest<>
            (
                    url,
                    new TypeToken<ArrayList<DummyObject>>() {}.getType(),
                    gson,
                    listener,
                    errorListener
            );
}
```

Java Object:

```
public class DummyObject
{
    private String mTitle;
    private String mBody;

    public String getTitle()
    {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        mTitle = title;
    }

    public String getBody()
    {
        return mBody;
    }

    public void setBody(String body)
    {
        mBody = body;
    }
}
```

Deserializer (not always necessary):

```
public class DummyObjectDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<DummyObject>
{
    @Override
    public DummyObject deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException
    {
        final DummyObject dummyObject = new DummyObject();
        final JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();

        dummyObject.setTitle(jsonObject.get("title").getAsString());
        dummyObject.setBody(jsonObject.get("body").getAsString());

        return dummyObject;
    }
}
```

If you have any problem just take a look at [this article](https://medium.com/android-news/android-networking-i-okhttp-volley-and-gson-72004efff196) and [this code](https://github.com/Sottti/OkHttpVolleyGsonSample).